# Composer Autoload - Can't find class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, silex

I have a little Silex app going on. Trying to get some sort of structure going on.

This is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.3"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "HelloWorld\\Controller": "src/HelloWorld/Controllers"
        }
    }
}
```

In my `web/index.php` file I have this

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$ctrl = new \HelloWorld\Controller\IndexController(); // <- Doesn't work
```

My `IndexController` controller in `src/HelloWorld/Controllers`

```
namespace HelloWorld\Controller;

class IndexController
{

}
```

I have tried pretty much every combination under the sun. Anyone know how to register it properly. The Silex stuff loads fine?

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'HelloWorld\Controller\IndexController' not found in /srv/http/web/index.php on line 6"`

Comment: I assume that at some point you ran ```composer install```, right?

Comment: That seemed to fix it after adding a psr-4 to the autload sesction too. Add it as an answer and I'll accept. Thanks :)

Comment: Done deal, glad it worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the autoloader file hasn't been generated so that it knows where to find the class. Try running

`composer install`

If you'd like to update the components of your website in the future, after the initial install, you can always run `composer update` to update the repositories.